# 551 Sender address is not valid for your login

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I have an asp.net C# webforms project that is hosted on IIS 7.5. Also mail server MailEnable server is used for sending/receiving mail.

In my project user is entering his mail address in the form and I need to send a mail with "from" field set to this user's email address and "to" set to some other user's email address.

Previously everything was working but now something is changed on the server so I've started getting messages:
"The server response was: Sender address is not valid for your login. Check your email program settings." that is 551 error according to http://www.mailenable.com/kb/Content/Article.asp?ID=me020032&SS=

So far I've found that this should be set:
1)"Authenticated senders must use valid sender address" -> disabled
2)"Allow relay for authenticated senders " -> enabled
3)"Address spoofing prevention" is set to "anyone can spoof sender's address"
But this didn't hepl.

What else should I check/change to make it work?

This are some parts of mail-sending code:
setting "from" field:

```
message.From = new MailAddress(context.From);
```

setting smtp parameters:

```
 SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient
 {
    Host = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTP_Server"],
    Port = Int32.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTP_Port"]),
    Credentials = new   System.Net.NetworkCredential(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTP_Login"],
  WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTP_Passw"]),
  Timeout = _timeOut,
  EnableSsl = Boolean.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSsl"])
};
```

I've checked in Plesk and smtp user that I am using for sending mail SMTP_Login/SMTP_Passw exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change settings as it was mentioned in the question:

1. "Authenticated senders must use valid sender address" -> disabled
2. "Allow relay for authenticated senders " -> enabled    "Address
3. spoofing prevention" is set to "anyone can spoof sender's address"

But the last step that I've missed was to restart the MailEnable. Maybe this will be helpfull for someone.